# How to export Bitbucket repo to pdf including the files content

Tags: git, pdf, bitbucket

is it possible to export an entire bitbucket git repo to pdf file?
I need to get a screenshot of an entire bitbucket repo including all the files and directories structure and contents.

I've seen several project like https://github.com/josherich/repo-to-pdf but nothing worked...

Comment: Do you want history too, or just a specific commit?

Comment: Everything but I can have only the files content

Comment: To clarify, suppose a file was modified in 1000 commits. In your PDF, do you want to see 1.) just the most recent version of that file, or 2.) the most recent version of the file (or maybe the original version) and a diff of the changes to that file for each of the other 999 commits, or 3.) all 1000 complete versions of that file?

Comment: Perhaps if you added some context as to *why* you want this PDF and/or what you plan to do with it, we may be able to offer more pinpointed solutions.

Comment: I need to provide to a non-tech lawyer a document that shows the exact content of the bitbucket repository on a specific date so he can archive it for future use...

Comment: a single pdf file with all the content from all the repository files would be great.

Comment: For that use case, a copy of the repo, or even a copy of the file system at a specific commit would make much more sense than a PDF. It would be annoying difficult to re-create the original files from a PDF, and binary files would not be presented in a meaningful way within a PDF.  If you're simply trying to prove ownership or "I made this before you did", there are many services that provide escrow or similar utilities that can associate any file(s) with a particular date. If you want just a single file, you could zip up the entire repo (or file system at a commit), and archive the zip file.

Comment: Since the goal is for proof of archiving rather than viewing, if for some reason the attorney *really* likes PDF files, I think you could zip up the repo and embed it in a PDF...

Comment: Way off to the side note, but maybe you should employ a "tech lawyer" instead of a "non-tech lawyer" for dealing with your tech property. ;)